# Is a line just an infinitely large circle?

Tags: circles, projective-geometry

> A line is infinite, right? Well, if $-\infty = \infty$, then a line is an infinitely large circle. (Does this have something to do with $1/0$?)

It seems wrong, is it? Could I disprove it? How would I state it to be more legitimate?