# 1/a approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, approximate-integration

I know very little calculus and I'm trying to understand [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUSv26BGU5I) from a MOOC I'm doing. I am trying to understand when at about 1:46 he says that $a$ doesn't approach infinity, but $1/a$ does. I though it was the exact opposite, am I taking something out of context? <sub><sup>*Please keep as little calculus in the answer as possible. Maybe one or two derivatives, integrals, or limits, but very little.*</sup></sub>

Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{1}0=\infty$.

Comment: @EdwardJiang $\pm$

Comment: @daOnlyBG Not in the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. ($\cong$ the Riemann sphere)

Comment: Didn't know you were referring to those domains; I'll rescind my answer since I'm not too familiar with circular number lines.

Comment: @EdwardJiang talk about it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068447/is-a-line-just-an-infinitely-large-circle)

Comment: area = 0 if $-\frac{1}{\infty}x$ and area = $\infty$ if $-\frac{1}{0}x$ very simple integral test

Comment: @EdwardJiang please don't claim that, this really doesn't make any sense... In terms of algebra that expression is undefined, in terms of analysis that expression is undefined as well (you would need to include limits of some sort).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $a$ decreases to $0$, then $1/a$ increases to $\infty$.

Imagine $a$ is some tiny tiny microscopic number, and you ask how many times $a$ goes into $1$.  It's a very large number.  And it can be made as large as you want by making $a$ small enough.

Answer (score 5):

When $a$ is close to $0$ the expression $e^{-ax}$ is close to $1$
which gives the intuition that 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\approx\int_{0}^{\infty}1\underbrace{=}_{\int_{a}^{b}c=c(b-a)}\infty
$$

and from the expressions $\frac{1}{a},1,a$ only $\frac{1}{a}$ is
large when $a$ is small.

For example if $a=0.001$ then $\frac{1}{a}=1000$.

On a side note - I think that you should be more comfortable with
limits when studying about improper integrals, maybe consider reviewing
this material

Answer (score 4):

The video isn't very clear because of the speaker's language and use of pronouns. What he means is that we cannot have $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \, dx = a $$ because $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \, dx \rightarrow \infty \,\, \text{as} \,\, a \rightarrow 0 $$ but, clearly, $a$ does not go to $\infty$ as $a \rightarrow 0.$ On the other hand, $\frac{1}{a} \rightarrow \infty$ as $a \rightarrow 0$ so that $\frac{1}{a}$ is a better candidate answer for the value of the integral.

Comment: better answer good use of the tests in the integrals. Much more helpful and not alot of calc

Comment: I wish I could select several correct answers